# Siteminder bypass authentication for specific IP address

Tags: siteminder

I have a resource/url that is protected by siteminder.  I would like to allow access to url for anyone coming from a specific IP address range.

If a browser is from a specific IP address range, I don't want them to Authenticate, they need to see the url without being prompted to log in.

Is there a way in siteminder to allow open access for specific IP address ranges, but require login for anyone outside of that range?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bad idea security wise since an IP address could be spoofed leaving your application completely open.  If you still wanted to continue I would look into using a load balancer/proxy to forward the request to another agent with a separate configuration.